# Create JNDI resource from code?

Tags: java, resources, jndi, naming

Is it possible to publish a custom/external resource to JNDI from within code? I know the way to do it is by administrator command [create-custom-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24938/create-custom-resource.htm#GSRFM00022) or from the administration gui.

Answer (score 4):

The JNDI api provides no mechanism for this, you would need to utilize the underlying implementation provided by the app server which is either not documented or poorly depending on the platform (in your case glassfish).